# ReportViewer Round() function

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, reportviewer

I am currently working with VS2005 + reportviewer and was wondering if there is a way to force report viewer to round up when the decimal is .5+ because currently it seems as if it rounds down until ".5" and then rounds up at ".6" for eg.

```
Round(20.5,0) //Returns 20
Round(20.6,0) //Returns 21
```

Strangely enough those are the results i get (I swear its supposed to round up at .5, atleast thats what i was taught in elementary school...)

Anyways if anyone knows how i can configure this issue or force it to round up at this point please let me know any help is appreciated thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Round(20.5, System.MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero)` instead